# Upload an html page to sharepoint

Tags: javascript, css, file-upload, html

I"ve been working on an html code (1 page only)
with functions (using Javascript and CSS) and it's all combined in one file named `menpower.html`.

I want to upload this html page to my SharePoint, so when a user clicks on a `'menu button'` in my SharePoint main page, it opens a new SharePoint page which displays my html page with all the JS functions and the CSS.

Is it possible? if it is, how do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: check this http://superuser.com/questions/35291/serve-normal-html-pages-from-a-sharepoint-server

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint designer, then you can upload your HTML file under Site pages section and just pass the URL.